# how to query using graphql useQuery method on button click or do query manually

Tags: reactjs, graphql

As on page load query is working fine, but my requirement is to query once again like a button click.

```
const JOB_LIST_QUERY = gql`
query detail($userId: Int!) {
candidate(id:$userId){
  id
  selected:manageCandidates(status:5){
    id
    interviewType
    interviewDate
  }
 }
}
;`

const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(JOB_LIST_QUERY, {
variables: {
  userId: Number.parseInt(userId.toString()),
},
onCompleted: data => {
  setSelectedJobList(data.candidate.selected)
},
onError: error => {
  console.log(error.message)
}
});
```

on button click, I want to do the query once again.
is there any possible way to declare within a function so that it canbe called on button click and on page load too.

Comment: it's possible, just do the query in an onClick handler, but the hook ```useQuery``` is likely not to be able to do that (expect if it provides such a thing like ```{loading, error, data, updateQuery} = useQuery```. Which graphql client are you using ?

Answer (score 2):

you can [`useLazyQuery`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/#uselazyquery) the hook will return a function that you can manually call, IE on component load or on click.

```
function Hello() {
  const [loadGreeting, { called, loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(
    GET_GREETING,
    { variables: { language: "english" } }
  );

  if (called && loading) return <p>Loading ...</p>

  if (!called) {
    return <button onClick={() => loadGreeting()}>Load greeting</button>
  }

  return <h1>Hello {data.greeting.message}!</h1>;
}
```